# Unicode Data support in hive

Tags: hadoop, unicode, hive

Hive supports unicode data in table as per the Hive documentation.

I create a table with "string" datatype and laded unicode data into it, but when I say `select * from <tablename>` I get junk values

```
create table unicode (data string);
load data local inpath 'unicode.txt' into table unicode;
```

Below is the output of select

```
Les caractï¿½res accentuï¿½s (Franï¿½ais)

En donnï¿½es nous avons confiance

Donnï¿½es, donnï¿½es, partout
et tous les noeuds ï¿½taient dï¿½connectï¿½

Donnï¿½es, donnï¿½es, partout
ni aucun bit ï¿½ traiter
```

**Original content**
    Les caractères accentués (Français)

```
En données nous avons confiance

Données, données, partout
et tous les noeuds étaient déconnecté

Données, données, partout
ni aucun bit à traiter
```

can someone suggest what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Create table query in your case creates a table with using the default hive serde i.e. simple lazy serde, this serde doesnt handle the unicode.

In order to handle unicode you need to define the table with other serdes like textinput or rcserde.

Comment: Whenever i set hive table has  stored as sequencefile or text file, every time it goes with lazy serilaizer how can i set textinput or rcserde

Answer (score 0):

Save your text file as UTF-8 encoding and then load data to your hive table. Other encoding types are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

like mysql, you can use '`' to quote unicode column name, but table name is not support.

```
create table test_t1 (
`编号` INT,
`名称` STRING,
`创建时间` TIMESTAMP
)

insert into test_t1 values(1,'lily',unix_timestamp())

select * from test_t1 where `编号`=1
```